# regarding variable assignment to matrix

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
>>> class prof:
...     def __init__(self,q,Q):
...         self.q,self.Q = q,Q
...     def profitmatrix(self):
...          q,Q= self.q,self.Q,
...          pimat=np.empty([1, Q+1])
...          list1=[]
...          for z in range(Q+1):
...              list1.append(z/(2**(z+1)))
...              sum1=sum(list1)+(Q/(2**(Q+1)))
...              for i in range(Q+1):
...                  if i<=q:
...                      pimat[:,i]=sum1
...                  else:
...                      pimat[:,i]=0
...                      return pimat
... 
>>> y= prof(1,2)
>>> print y.profitmatrix()
[[ 0.25  0.25  0.  ]]
>>> sum1
0.75
```

I want to assign elements of pimat the value sum1. but inspite of remembering the value of sum1 it is getting altered once the program continues into the loop. I dont know why that is happening**strong text**

Comment: The `sum1` variable you see outside the method is completely unrelated to the variable inside the `profitmatrix` method.

Comment: Yes. But i need the sum1 values to create the profitmatrix and I cudnt find a better way.

Comment: All I want is python to remember sum1 when it enters the loop for assigning values to the matrix. But some how despite of remembering that sum1=.75, it is assigning .25 to the desired elements of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are overwriting the value of sum1 in the loop. This may be the answer but it's unclear as to exactly what you want to do:

```
import numpy as np

class prof:
     def __init__(self,q,Q, sum1):
         self.q,self.Q = q,Q
     def profitmatrix(self):
          q,Q= self.q,self.Q,
          pimat=np.empty([1, Q+1])
          list1=[]
          for z in range(Q+1):
              list1.append(z/(2**(z+1)))
              suma=sum(list1)+(Q/(2**(Q+1)))
              for i in range(Q+1):
                  if i<=q:
                      pimat[:,i]=sum1
                  else:
                      pimat[:,i]=0
                      return pimat


sum1 = 0.75
y= prof(1,2, sum1)
print y.profitmatrix()
```

What @user2357112 is correct, whatever you are trying to do, sum1 variable in the scope of the class is a different one to the one you are accessing at the end of the script.